# API to intercept network traffic

Tags: macos, cocoa, tcp, firewall

Could some give a hint at which API one would **intercept in- and outgoing network traffic** like [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index-de.html) does on **Mac OS X**?

A cocoa based API is favored.

Would one need to write a [kext](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptAnatomy/kext_anatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002364-SW3) or would an - somehow authorized - user-land app could do the job too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how Little Snitch does it (but I'd love to…); I've been using these dTrace probes:

# Socket accepts by process name:

dtrace -n 'syscall::accept*:entry { @[execname] = count(); }'

# Socket connections by process and user stack trace:

dtrace -n 'syscall::connect*:entry { trace(execname); ustack(); }'

# Who is connecting to what:

dtrace -n 'tcp:::accept-established { @[args[3]->tcps_raddr, args[3]->tcps_lport] = count(); }'

(these are from "DTrace: Dynamic Tracing in Oracle Solaris, Mac OS X, and FreeBSD by Brendan Gregg and Jim Mauro, Prentice Hall 2011"  http://www.dtracebook.com/index.php/Network_Lower_Level_Protocols.)

You should also checkout Brendan Gregg's DTraceToolkit: http://www.brendangregg.com/dtrace.html#DTraceToolkit

Specifically tcpsnoop and tcptop.